# How can I save and load some man menu settings like volume?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using System;

public class Settings : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioMixer audioMixer;
    public TMP_Dropdown resolutionDropdown;
    public Text musicText;
    public Text sfxText;
    public Slider[] audioSliders;

    private Resolution[] resolutions;

    private void Start()
    {
        resolutions = Screen.resolutions;

        resolutionDropdown.ClearOptions();

        List<string> options = new List<string>();

        int currentResolutionIndex = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < resolutions.Length; i++)
        {
            string option = resolutions[i].width + " x " + resolutions[i].height;
            options.Add(option);

            if(resolutions[i].width == Screen.currentResolution.width &&
                resolutions[i].height == Screen.currentResolution.height)
            {
                currentResolutionIndex = i;
            }
        }

        resolutionDropdown.AddOptions(options);
        resolutionDropdown.value = currentResolutionIndex;
        resolutionDropdown.RefreshShownValue();

        float musicvolume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("musicvolume");
        float sfxvolume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("sfxvolume");

        musicText.text = musicvolume.ToString();
        sfxText.text = sfxvolume.ToString();
        audioSliders[0].value = musicvolume;
        audioSliders[1].value = sfxvolume;
    }

    public void SetResolution(int resolutionIndex)
    {
        Resolution resolution = resolutions[resolutionIndex];
        Screen.SetResolution(resolution.width, resolution.height, Screen.fullScreen);
    }

    public void SetMusicVolume(float volume)
    {
        audioMixer.SetFloat("musicvol", Mathf.Log10(volume) * 20);
        musicText.text = Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();

        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("musicvolume", (float)Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
    }

    public void SetSfxVolume(float volume)
    {
        audioMixer.SetFloat("sfxvol", Mathf.Log10(volume) * 20);
        sfxText.text = Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();

        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("sfxvolume", (float)Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
    }

    public void SetQuality(int qualityIndex)
    {
        QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(qualityIndex);
    }

    public void SetFullscreen(bool isFullscreen)
    {
        Screen.fullScreen = isFullscreen;
    }
}
```

In the Start() I'm loading :

```
        float musicvolume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("musicvolume");
        float sfxvolume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("sfxvolume");

        musicText.text = musicvolume.ToString();
        sfxText.text = sfxvolume.ToString();
        audioSliders[0].value = musicvolume;
        audioSliders[1].value = sfxvolume;
```

And then saving in the two methods :

```
public void SetMusicVolume(float volume)
        {
            audioMixer.SetFloat("musicvol", Mathf.Log10(volume) * 20);
            musicText.text = Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();
    
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("musicvolume", (float)Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
        }
    
        public void SetSfxVolume(float volume)
        {
            audioMixer.SetFloat("sfxvol", Mathf.Log10(volume) * 20);
            sfxText.text = Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();
    
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("sfxvolume", (float)Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
        }
```

When I'm changing the sliders volume while the game is running it's saving and loading fine the text and set the value in the text but it's not changing the sliders values the sliders always start at the most right end side.

For example I'm setting the music volume to 44 when the game is running :

[image: Volume is set to 44]

Then I stop the game and run it again :

In the Audiomixer on the right up in the Music group the slider is on 0 and in the game the slider is at the most right end side but the text value show 44.

How can I make that it will change also the slider value to 44 and not only the slider text ?

[image: The text value is 44 but the slider value is not 44]

This is what I'm doing in the Start() to set the slider/s value :

```
audioSliders[0].value = musicvolume;
audioSliders[1].value = sfxvolume;
```

but it's not changing it when running the game the value of the slider is 100 and the text value is 44.

And the same idea I want to save/load all the main menu settings.

Screenshot of the music slider inspector settings :

[image: Music slider settings in inspector]

Comment: Are the sliders' min and max values correct after loading? also check the value in the Inspectors, are they "correct"?

Comment: You could also try and actively force saving the PlayerPrefs via `PlayerPrefs.Save();` By default this only happens in `OnApplicationQuit` but in general anyways you should do it on certain "checkpoints" during runtime

Comment: @derHugo The values in both sliders are min = 0.0001 and max  = 1 and the Value property is set to 1. This min and max are for making the calculations in the methods SetMusicVolume and SetFsxVolume. Maybe I need to perform this calculations also in the Start ?

Comment: I added another screenshot of the music slider inspector settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm seeing now that when you  store the value you do

```
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("musicvolume", (float)Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
```

doesn't that mean that in `Start`  you would need to do

```
audioSliders[0].value = musicvolume / 100f;
```

The fact that your slider also goes from `0.0001` to `1` sounds like passing `44` (the value you stored) as `value` is not what you wanted. It needs to be `0.44` instead, the original slider value before multiplying by `100` and storing the result.

Or alternatively I would actually rather store the correct slider value in the PlayerPrefs and do any calculations only for the applied volume and the display but use the raw values for the slider. But that's of course purely a matter of taste.

Comment: What do you mean passing 44 as value ? I set the min max from this tutorial https://gamedevbeginner.com/the-right-way-to-make-a-volume-slider-in-unity-using-logarithmic-conversion/ Shoul I change the min max ?

Comment: the min max is fine .. but when you set the value you store `volume * 100` .. since the text after loading is `44` I know this is the value you stored .. however when again applying it to the slider it again has to be `0.44` since the slider uses values between 0 and 1. If you pass in `value = 44` it is clamped to the max value .. that's the reason why the slider after loading was always at `1`